# Least-restrictive memory ordering for single-producer, single-consumer ringbuffer?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-barriers

I have a RingBuffer which services one consumer and one producer and uses two integers to detect new data:

```
_lastReadIndex
_lastWrittenIndex
```

so there is unread data in the ringbuffer when these two values are not equal.

The Producer **increments** (and moduluses with the ringbuffer size to wrap-around) `_lastWrittenIndex` when an item is added to the ringbuffer.

The Consumer spins, **reading** both values, checking for new data and when there is, it will **increment** (and modulus) `_lastReadIndex`.

The three highlighted terms emphasise the requirements with regard to multithreading and memory barriers.

How far can I relax the memory ordering for this design, accounting for Intel's memory model? I believe Intel's memory model allows loads to be re-ordered with earlier stores to different addresses?

EDIT using the C++11 atomic library `std::memory_order_xxxx` etc

Comment: So do you want c++11 atomics, or architecture-dependent decision (using assembler) for Intel? In the first case architecture is unrelated, in the second - `c++` tag is unrelated.

Comment: Sorry, C++11 libraries

Comment: The thing is that your indexing in the ring buffer, depends on reading the `_lastReadIndex` value and **then** the modulo. So it is two separate actions. If it only was for reading the value in `_lastReadIndex`, `acquire` for read and `release` for the writes would suffice.

Comment: You need to be concerned with whatever is written into the ring-buffer as well as `_lastWrittenIndex`. You will need to ensure in-order execution of the writes as well (with the data completing first, or at worse, concurrently with the index).  You want a release/acquire on the data and a re-order barrier prevent re-ordering of the writes.

Comment: memory_order_relaxed probably works just fine since you're spinning so guaranteed to eventually see the update.  If the buffer is big enough then you don't care that much about not being to fill it to capacity.  Spinning is ugly and rarely desirable.  Fix that and you no longer care.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought spinning would be the fastest solution to "see" the data as soon as possible?

Comment: Balancing the merits of "fast" with burning 100% core is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you have to do before anything else:

Modulus the reading and writing points, but keep `_lastReadIndex` and `_lastWrittenIndex` intact to know how much data you have available, how much is lost, or mayhaps block on writer if it overruns the reader after full cycle.

And, very importantly, avoid sharing as much as possible - put the reader and writer variables on separate cache lines.

Now, to your question:

If you're trying to be portable, the memory ordering you'd require in your code should not consider the architecture. The standard atomic functions can take care of this.
You only need to make sure data available in the buffer before incrementing the write index, which means release semantics on the increment.
You also have to make sure the writer writes data to memory, and not optimized to remain only in registers.

```
newIndex = _lastWrittenIndex+1;
buffer[newIndex % bufSize] = newData;
atomic_store( &_lastWrittenIndex, newIndex, memory_order_release );
```

On x86/64, this will be the same as:

```
newIndex = _lastWrittenIndex+1;
buffer[newIndex % bufSize] = newData;
// release semantics means reorder barrier before action:
barrier(); // translates to `asm volatile("":::"memory");`
*(volatile int*)_lastWrittenIndex = newIndex;
```

When writing code that accesses `_lastWrittenIndex` not more than absolutely necessary, like above, you may as well declare it volatile but keep in mind the barrier is still needed!

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that when the consumer reads _lastWrittenIndex, it must use an atomic_load with memory_order_acquire.  Also, _lastReadIndex needs similar treatment, because in effect the consumer is transmitting empty slots to the producer.